# How to load relations to TypeORM tree entities?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a group entity which is a tree structure and a user entity which is another tree structure.

Group:

```
@Entity()
@Tree("closure-table")
export class Group {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id: number;

   @Column()
   name: String;

   @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.group)
   user: User[];

   @TreeChildren()
   children: Group[];

   @TreeParent()
   parent: Group;

   @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.group)
   leader: User[];
}
```

User:

```
 @Entity()
    @Tree("closure-table")
    export class User {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id: number;

   @Column()
   userName: String;

   @Column()
   name: String;

   @Column()
   phoneNumber: String;

   @ManyToOne(() => Role, role => role.user)
   role: Role;

   @ManyToOne(() => Group, group => group.user)
   group: Group;
   
   @TreeChildren()
   children: User[];

   @TreeParent()
   parent: User;
}
```

I would like to get the tree structure so that users are included.
Do you know any solution for this? Because when I use groupsRepository.findTrees() then the relationship is not included in the query.

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I have the same problem currently..

Comment: You should write another query and map them. 
Unfortunately there is no other workaround :/